# how to increase and decrease line by clicking on it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi friends I am trying to do my contact us page like this page "http://makingsense.com/about-us", I started and I've tried this much but i couldn't get clear idea how to do.

See code: http://jsfiddle.net/cu65a45r/

```
    // JavaScript Document
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('.clik1').on('click', function() {
    /*   $('.date-circle-active').remove();*/
         $(this).before("<div class='date-circle-active1'></div>");
         $(this).css('margin-left','0');
     });
      $('.clik2').on('click', function() {
    /*   $('.date-circle-active').remove();*/
         $(this).before("<div class='date-circle-active2'></div>");
         $(this).css('margin-left','0');
     });
});
```

Comment: Try slideIn and slideOut jquery commands?

Comment: Just wondering, what does PLZ stand for?

Comment: @musefan German for 'zip', sort of lolspeak gone awry or simply a typo - you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cu65a45r/6/)

The key differences between my approach and your's:

1. I keep `.move-more` and `.data-circle`'s as siblings.
2. I add `position: relative` to the container so it would be easy to track relative offset of it's children `.data-circle`s.
3. When someone clicks on the circle, I read it's offset to the container (`.move`) and set  `offset.left` value as a width to the `.move-more` element.

JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('.date-circle').on('click', function() {
     // let's cache link to jQuery wrapper around current circle
     var $this = $(this);
     // remove active class from siblings
     $this.siblings().removeClass('date-circle-active');
     // and add it to the current circle
     $this.addClass('date-circle-active');

     // get left coordinate of current circle relative to .move container
     var leftOffset = $this.offset().left;
     // and set width of the red line to this value
     // I remove 5 pixel that is the width of the circle's border so that .move-more won't spoil yellow background of the circle
     $('.move-more').animate({'width': (leftOffset - 5) + 'px'}, 'fast');
   });
});
```

Comment: here what you done is mearly correct but while i click back it is not going back.

Comment: It's red line overlapped circles.

Comment: You can click not on the center of the circles, but a bit higher or lower and it will work.

Comment: I just added one line to stylesheet and added z-index to .move-more.